# Metro stopped while application downloading in android - Facing problem in running react native application on android using vs code windows

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, node-modules

I have followed steps using react native official website

https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?package-manager=npm

when I am running `npm start` and then `npm run android` application is installed but error of metro not running come.
Solved this problem by running metro in a different port say 8088.

But now when i use `npm start -- --port=8088` and then `npm run android` getting below error

Then metro stopped while application downloading in android and getting below error in metro terminal -

```
r - reload the app
d - open developer menu
i - run on iOS
a - run on Android

node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'D:\React-native_Projects\Infovision_demo_rn_js_ts_final_projects\rn_cli\RnJsMvvmProjectNew\android\app\build\intermediates\stripped_native_libs\debug\out\lib\arm64-v8a\libevent-2.1.so.tmp70b4bc8'
Emitted 'error' event on NodeWatcher instance at:
    at D:\React-native_Projects\Infovision_demo_rn_js_ts_final_projects\rn_cli\RnJsMvvmProjectNew\node_modules\metro-file-map\src\watchers\NodeWatcher.js:231:14 {
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'lstat',
  path: 'D:\\React-native_Projects\\Infovision_demo_rn_js_ts_final_projects\\rn_cli\\RnJsMvvmProjectNew\\android\\app\\build\\intermediates\\stripped_native_libs\\debug\\out\\lib\\arm64-v8a\\libevent-2.1.so.tmp70b4bc8'
}
```

and in android device (image added)

[image]

I have tried to uninstall and re install all packages and npm also.

there is one solution in this video - [click](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPYez4cs5LY&ab_channel=ThelleCodes), but in my project node module there is not a blacklist.js file, I have created project several time it is not there.

I am using below versions
npm v9.5.1
node v18.16.1
react-native@latest